# PayPal IPN/PDT for multiple sites

Tags: paypal

We have 4 websites that sell 4 separate (and unrelated products), and all of them use the same PayPal account. All 4 sites provide options for paying with PayPal Standard, and PayPal Website Payments Pro.

The 'Pro' side of things works fine. The area we have a problem is with the IPN settings. As we have 4 "Notification URL's" what should we enter in the IPN settings?

Has anyone found a way to set this up properly?

(I use quite a few other SE sites, but this one looked most likely to answer a PayPal question. If it's not, please migrate it or tell me and I'll delete and repost. Thanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can specify the Notifications URL when the payment is made through the `notify_url` parameter. In your PayPal profile, you'll set the Notifications URL to either one of your stores, as long as it's a valid URL. That will be overriden with the Notification URL you pass during the payment.